# Lexicographical Arrangement - PHP

Tags: php

I have 'solutions' like "4 2 10 5 0 3", "0 10 2 5 4 3". (just an example)

How to get the lexicographically smallest solution? What does this mean? The program is in PHP. I tried exploding them by " " and using `min()` function on the arrays generated but that's not giving correct solution.

Comment: hmmmm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order ...lexicographic order refers to dictionary order; in the case of numbers if you have 101, 1 and 11 a normal sort would yield 1, 101, 11, however a natural sort (lexicographic) would be how you and i understand it: 1, 11, 101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try natural sort order

```
$strVal1 = "4 2 10 5 0 3";

$arrVal1 = explode(" ", $strVal1); 

natsort($arrVal1); //will sort array as 0,2,3,4,5,10

$minVal = $arrVal1[0]; 

echo $minVal; //should return 0
```

EDIT: as per your comment

```
//let's suppose you have an array of string values as in your example
//and $strVal1 = ""4 2 10 5 0 3", $strVal2 = "0 10 2 5 4 3" and so on
$strVals = array($strVal1, $strVal2 , $strVal3 , ... ,$strValN)

//just sort it naturally and there you have it :)
natsort($strVals); 

//the smallest element is first
echo $strVals[0];
```

PHP natsort() function reference - [check here](https://www.php.net/natsort)

Comment: I don't want to sort individual numbers, I want the multiple strings in lexicographical order